# What is the smallest diameter of a set of $n$ points in the plane which are all at least 2 meters apart from each other?

Tags: graph-theory, plane-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, tiling, packing-problem

This question is similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle except I am looking for the smallest diameter, i.e: I want the smallest maximum distance between the centers of the circles, rather than the smallest circle which contains them. Asymptotically these solutions should roughly be the same of course.

This is not the same as just circle packings. For instance; two equilateral triangles of length $2m$ have a smaller area than a square of length $2m$. But the diameter of those equilateral triangles is $\sqrt3$, whereas the diameter of the square is $\sqrt2$.

I don't expect that general solutions for $n$ exist, but examples of values for small $n$ would be helpful

To be clear, by diameter I mean the maximum distance between two points.

Comment: Is your question about smallest area (like your supposed counterexample mentions) or the smallest diameter? If the latter, then it really is just circle packing, where you subtract 2 metres from the diameter of the bounding circle to get the minimum diameter around the points themselves.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yeah the area comment was bad, was not thinking straight when writing the question out. Again, the diameter question is not equivalent to circles since two centers of circles are not necessarily diametrically opposite. The diameter of the set of points could be smaller than the diameter of the circle. Check n=5 in the wikipedia article Iinked to see why your solution of taking 2 meters from diameter wouldn't necessarily yield the optimum diameter

Comment: The small circles in the wiki article have diameter 1. You want diameter 2, so you have to scale everything up by a factor 2. The enclosing circle of the n=5 case then has diameter 2*2.701=5.402. The centres of the small circles lie on a circle of diameter 3.402. So in general the answers you want are the numbers listed there, multiplied by 2 and then minus 2.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis You haven't understood the issue. The diameter of the circle will not be equal to the diameter of the points because on the new circle the points won't necessarily lie diametrically opposite

Comment: I see what you mean now. Since you are optimising on the largest distance rather than on the bounding overall bounding diameter there might be a more optimal arrangement that is not quite circular. This is more likely for small n. Looking at the wiki page, n=10 and n=11 look like the most promising ones for this making a difference due to the large gap between the circles around the outside, though the difference it might make will be tiny.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis:  No, it is no different.  Draw the line segment between the farthest two points.  Extend it $1m$ beyond each point.  That is the smallest circle that contains all the points with a $1m$ circle around them, which forces the points to be $2m$ apart.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via nonlinear programming as follows.  For $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, let $(x_i,y_i)$ be the coordinates of point $i$.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to
$$z \ge \sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2} \ge 2$$
for $1\le i<j \le n$.  Here are upper bounds (not necessarily optimal) for small $n$:
\begin{array}{cc}
n &z &\text{description}\\
\hline
1 &0 &\text{trivial}\\
2 &2 &\text{trivial}\\
3 &2 &\text{equilateral triangle}\\
4 &2\sqrt{2}=2.8284 &\text{square}\\
5 &1+\sqrt{5}=3.2361 &\text{regular pentagon}\\
6 &\sqrt{2(5+\sqrt{5})}=3.8042 &\text{regular pentagon plus center}\\
7 &4 &\text{regular heptagon}\\
8 &\sec(3\pi/7)=4.4940 &\text{regular heptagon plus center}\\
9 &5.1385 \\
10 &5.5546 \\
11 &5.7349 \\
12 &5.8186 \\
13 &6.3024 \\
14 &6.6317 \\
15 &6.9393 \\
16 &7.1803 \\
17 &7.5075 \\
18 &7.6747 \\
19 &4\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=7.7274 \\
20 &8.1816 
\end{array}
Here's $n=19$: [image]